# Transfer a site from SQLite to MySQL

Tags: database, backups

Is it possible to transfer the content of a site that I develop locally with SQLite as a database to the live site which uses MySQL or PostgreSQL when it is finished?

I don't want to have to install MySQL or PostgresSQL locally on my laptop. Can [backup_migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module do it or does it export raw MySQL instructions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the [DBTNG Migrator](http://drupal.org/project/dbtng_migrator) module.

> This module is a UI and Drush interface to replicate a database from one database to another independant of what kind of database server they are. So long as ther are support by Drupal, you can migrate to them, including non-SQL stuff!

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. I migrated two drupal installations from sqlite to mysql and I noticed a performance improvement. Just a couple of notes (if they might be of help), take the site offline before doing the migration and in my case at least, I had to disable secure pages, Locale and uninstall the Spanish language pack, then reinstalled them back again. In general, disable any unnecessary module/feature that might interfere with the migration process (I think they are very few).

Answer (score 0):

i have a lot of trobles doing that. So finnaly i did it, so what do you need to do migration goes well:

1. Delete other languages from site, exept english
2. disable locale, and localization update module.
3. Make migration in empty mysql database with dbtng migration module
4. You will have trobles with enable languages at new database, so
   create a fresh install of drupal and make export tables trought
   phpMyadmin: languages, locales_sorce and locales_target.
5. Import them to new mysql migration website database

Hope it help somebody