# How to Migrate from SQLite to MySQL?

Tags: 8, database, migrations, backups

I built a Drupal 8 site using SQLite. Performance is awful, so I'd like to use MySQL instead.  What's the best way to go about this?

A step-by-step guide would be nice, but any advice and tips are appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See also: [Transfer a site from SQLite to MySQL](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/4135/9223)

Comment: @unor that link is for Drupal 7

Comment: @ParagMagunia: Yes, that’s why it’s just a "see also" and not suggested as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I've used their product (MSSQL to MySQL) but a place to start might be here:

https://dbconvert.com/sqlite/mysql/

For me it worked flawlessly converting a MSSQL database with 10 years of data into MySQL so I could import it to Drupal 7. I would expect the same quality in this sister product, it's worth a look.

Comment: Thanks. This appears to be a $150 product. There is a trial version, but it has limitations and watermarks database records. I assume Drupal configuration files would need to be modified as well to use a new database driver.

Comment: For MySQL? I figured if you converted the database to MySQL, you could import it and set a database connecting to it in settings.php and specify the driver as MySQL. If it works, Drupal wouldn't know the difference. And yeah I paid the $100 for a license because the trial result was promising.

Comment: Which is exactly what I did, I converted, imported to MySQL as a new database, created another connection key in settings.php and voila, it worked. You can try that same approach and see what happens.

Comment: Get the trial version of navicat premium installed, it's free for 14 days and you can literally drag tables from a MSSQL database to a mysql one. Drupal won't know or care